# Django Custom User Model is not using The model manager while creating normal users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a user from the Django rest framework's ModelViewset. (However, I've also tried to do the same with regular Django's model form. In both cases, the CustomUser model is not using the create_user function from the Model manager.

My codes are as follows:

**Model Manager**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, phone, full_name, **other_fields):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a full name")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("User must have a phone number")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            phone=phone,
            full_name=full_name,
            is_active=True,
        )
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        user.set_password(phone)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, phone, full_name, password=None, **other_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email")
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("User must have a password")
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("User must have a full name")
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError("User must have a phone number")

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name = full_name,
            phone = phone
        )
        user.set_password(password)  # change password to hash
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

**Model:**

```
class CustomUserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, AbstractModel):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField( max_length=150, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['phone', 'full_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.username} - {self.email}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.username:
            uid = str(uuid4()).split('-')[1].upper()
            today = str(date.today()).replace('-', '').swapcase()
            splitted_uname = self.full_name.split(' ')[0][:2].upper()
            self.username = f'{splitted_uname}-{uid}{today}'
        super(CustomUserModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Django REST Framework's ViewSet**

```
class UserBaseViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    allowed_methods = ('GET', 'POST', 'PATCH')
    serializer_class = serializers.UserBaseListSerializer
    queryset = CustomUserModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsProfileOwnerOrReadOnly, ]
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return serializers.UserBaseDetailSerializer
        return super().get_serializer_class()
```

While creating superusers from the **command line** it works perfectly.
What am I missing in this process?
I debug the process but the model class doesn't users the create_user function of the manager in any way.

Comment: You will have to override `create` of `UserBaseListSerializer` to call the manager's `create_user`

Comment: Can you show me the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override `create` of `UserBaseListSerializer` to call the manager's `create_user`:

```
class UserBaseListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUserModel.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```